# Embedding SociableKit breaks my Flexslider on website

Tags: javascript, flexslider

As i wanted a method of embedding google reviews to my website I went with SocialbleKit.

Embedding this in my website caused issues. The following is the code provided by socialble to embed.

-->

```
    <div class="container-wrap">
        <aside id="fh5co-hero">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slider-img2.jpg);">
                    <!--<div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                    <h1>Free Estimates</h1>
                                        <h2></h2>
                                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-demo" href="#"></i> Portfolio</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-learn">Learn More</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                </li>
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slider-img3.jpg);">
                    <!--<div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-push-3 slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-inner">
                                    <h1>WordPress Theme For People Who Tell Stories</h1>
                                        <h2>Free html5 templates Made by <a href="http://freehtml5.co/" target="_blank">freehtml5.co</a></h2>
                                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-demo" href="#"></i> View Demo</a> <a class="btn btn-primary btn-learn">Learn More</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                </li>
                <li style="background-image: url(images/slider-img4.png);">
                    <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
                    <div class="container-fluids">
                        
                            <!--<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-md-pull-3 slider-text">
                                <div class="slider-text-before text-center">
                                    <h1>BEFORE&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AFTER</h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>-->

                        
                    </div>
                </li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </aside>
```

Tried different div classes and containers with no avail